# CSS on Tumblr - Space between header and navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I made some changes to my Tumblr so that it can match my Wordpress blog. I swapped the header out, but now I have a huge space between the header and the nav bar. Any ideas about how I can get rid of it?

You can see my Tumblr [here](http://gallery.lucearow.com).

I am trying to replicate my [blog](http://lucearow.com) as much as possible.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an empty container div.

Either delete the container, or put the following in the CSS;

```
#container {
   display: none;
}
```

or you could set the padding on the `#container` rule to 0.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: On closer look, you do need to delete your entire container. Delete all this code;

```
<div id="container">    
    <div class="blogtitle">
        <a href="/"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="description"></div>    
</div>
```

and then delete the styles for `#container`, `.blogtitle`, and `.description` (unless you think you might need them later).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I changed the padding to 0 which gets rid of a lot of the space, but not all of it. When you say empty container div do mean this: <div id="container"> at line 351? Should I just delete that line? If I add in the CSS where do I put it? I'm sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie with these things.

Comment: Ok, I see. I did that. That container must have been for the old header (the one I replaced). Still seeing a space though. I'm not sure how to have the exact same spacing as my blog.

Comment: If you want to get rid of more space, reduce the padding in your stylesheet on the `ul#list-nav` element. It's currently set at 44px.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked. Looks like I can't upvote without a certain reputation score. Any ideas on how to change the space between the links on the nav menu?

Comment: After the `}` bracket for `ul#list-nav`, add the following `ul#list-nav a { padding: 0px 10px; }` and feel free to play around with the numbers. The first number is the top and bottom padding, and the second is the left and right.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing you web site I found the issue: Just you need to make following change in CSS:

```
div#page{
    margin: 0px;
}

#masthead{
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where do I put that code?

Comment: This is a css class. You have to place it inside style tag.

Comment: Yes, I did but I still have a space there. I don't know how to set the space to be exactly the same as my blog. The header on my Tumblr is not responsive, so I don't know if that's part of the problem.

Comment: I reviewed your site once, and I have updated the solution. Check it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to decrease the space by changing the padding.

Comment: You can decrease the space in many ways. So finally how's it?

Comment: It's good! I am curious as to how I change the spacing between the links in the nav bar?

Comment: You can do it in many ways by adjusting top,right,left,bottom of margin, padding css properties. As the above answer solved your issue you can mark it as accepted answer and mark as useful answer.